# Lightweight, mobile compatible, modern, free alternative to FancyBox 2

Tags: open-source, css-transitions, javascript, fancybox-2

I am looking for an alternative to FancyBox 2. It should be lightweight, mobile friendly (use hardware accelerated css transitions), and free to use commercially (FancyBox isn't).
Any good alternatives?

Answer (score 21):

I think [Swipebox](http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/) is the closest I've seen to what you're after. It doesn't look exactly the same as fancybox, but it is a lightbox, mobile-friendly, uses css transitions, and appears to be free for commercial use

Comment: Thanks! Can it be used to display iframes and other DOM elements (like div)?

Comment: It looks like it has some support for that (video for example: http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/#advanced). I don't know any more than you do though, check out the docs!

Comment: Be aware, it's a jQuery plugin. Non-jQuery alternative licenced under MIT is https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery#lightbox-setup (which does NOT require jQuery, but can be also used as a jQuery plugin if needed)